# como fazer query nativa com paginação?

Tags: query

Estou conseguindo fazer um select simples, mas não sei a estrutura de como fazer um select usando join. Segue o código abaixo:

Esse código funciona:

```
   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tabela1  /*#pageable*/",
   countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM tabela1",
   nativeQuery = true)
   Page<ClasseModeloTabela> testePaginacaoQuery(Pageable pageable);
```

Esse código não funciona a sintaxe está errada?

```
 @Query(value = "select i.* " + "from tabela1 r 
 /*#pageable*/"
 + "join tabela2 ri on ri.chavetabela2 = 
 r.chavetabela1 "
 + "join tabela3 i on i.chavetabela3 = 
 ri.chavetabela2"
 + "where r.NR_campo1 = ?1 or i.campo2 =?2 ",
 countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM tabela1",
 nativeQuery = true)
 public Page<ClasseModeloTabela> testePaginacaoQueryJoin(Long campo1, 
 Long campo2, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

já achei a resposta, para quem tiver interessado a sintaxe é a seguinte:

```
@Query(value = "select i.* " + "from tabela1 r  "
+ "join tabela2 ri on ri.chavetabela2 = r.chavetabela1  "
+ "join tabela3 i on i.chavetabela3 = ri.chavetabela2 "
+ "where r.campo1 = ?1 or i.campo2 =?2 /*#pageable*/ ",
 countQuery = "SELECT count(*) "
+"from tabela1 r  "
+ "join tabela2 ri on ri.chavetabela2 = r.chavetabela1  "
+ "join tabela3 i on i.chavetabela3 = ri.chavetabela2 "
+ "where r.campo1 = ?1 or i.campo2 =?2  ",
   nativeQuery = true)
      public Page<ClasseModeloTabela> testePaginacaoQueryJoin(Long campo1, Long campo2, Pageable pageable);
```